# Issue on Appending to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the jquery `.each()` and `.appendTo()` functions to dynamically append `.chartBox` to each of `.paneldiv` divs existing in `.toprow` AND specifying **different ID** for each of newly generated boxes like `#chart1`  ,`#chart2`  ,`#chart3`  using following code

```
<div id="toprow">
<div class="paneldiv"></div>
<div class="paneldiv"></div> 
<div class="paneldiv"></div>
</div>

<script>
   $("button").on("click", function () {
        var rtop = $("#toprow").height();

        $("#toprow < .paneldiv").each(function(){
              var newDiv = $("<div />", {
            "class": "chartBox",
            "id": "chart?"
        }).css({
            "background-color": "yellow",
            "font-weight": "bolder",
            "height": rtop+"px",
            "width" : "100%"
        }).appendTo("?");
   });
 </script>
```

but I have issues on < br />
1 - How Can I apply Different ID for each dynamically added .`.chartBox`  ? 
2 - How can I use the `.appendTo()` method here to append the new box with new ID to next .paneldiv` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback for `each` can have two parameters that specify the index of the element and the element itself. Conveniently, you can use those:

```
<script>
   $("button").on("click", function () {
        var rtop = $("#toprow").height();

        $("#toprow < .paneldiv").each(function(index, element){
             var newDiv = $("<div />", {
                "class": "chartBox",
                "id": "chart" + index
                })
            .css({
                "background-color": "yellow",
                "font-weight": "bolder",
                "height": rtop+"px",
                "width" : "100%"
            })
            .appendTo(element);
   });
 </script>
```

Apart from that, you can also make a counter variable yourself and use that. And the callback of `each` is called in the context of the element, so the variable `this` also points to the element. So the code below is essentially the same as the one above:

```
<script>
   $("button").on("click", function () {
        var rtop = $("#toprow").height();
        var index = 0;
        $("#toprow < .paneldiv").each(function(){
             var newDiv = $("<div />", {
                "class": "chartBox",
                "id": "chart" + index++
                })
            .css({
                "background-color": "yellow",
                "font-weight": "bolder",
                "height": rtop+"px",
                "width" : "100%"
            })
            .appendTo(this);
   });
 </script>
```